# Find:$\int_{a}^{b}\ [x] dx + \int_{a}^{b}\ [-x] dx $

Tags: integration

Find following integration

$\int_{a}^{b}\ [x] dx + \int_{a}^{b}\ [-x] dx  $ where [.] denotes greatest integer function

Comment: Time to draw a picture.

Comment: but please also  not to use  empirical  words.like Find.simple  please help me  to  find it  or like this

Comment: Instead of continuing to rapidly fire questions without any kind of motivation or personal thoughts, you might want to slow down the pace and to add this kind of input to your future questions. In the present case, it is clear that you did not spend one minute to **think** about the question you were asking.

Comment: This is Section 1.15 Exercise 3 from Apostol's Calculus pg. 70

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that if $x$ is not an integer, then $\lfloor x \rfloor +\lfloor -x\rfloor=-1$. And the integral is not affected by function values at finitely many points. So the integral is $-(b-a)$.